# How to stop onclick event of master page on conent page textbox enter click

Tags: c#

I have two search options:

1. On Master Page there is a text box and button for search.
2. On content page there is a text box and button for search.

Now whenever I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key from keyboard, the masterpage button event is fires. I mean in every case when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key from keyboard the master page search button click event is called. I want If someone fill the content page search form and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, it fires content page event. Can anyone help me about this issue?

**Author edit from answer**

I have 2 search controls: one in master page which i am showing on every page, and one in content page which is my search page which displays search results. I have written code in master page button click which will redirect to content page which displays search result.

1. From home page i am typing some text in master page search textbox and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>from keyboard. As per coding it is redirecting to my search result page which is content page.
2. Now i am typing some text in my search result page which is content page and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> from keyboard till this steps it works fine.
3. Now when type some text in master page search textbox again and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> from keyborad instead of taking `onclick` of master page search button it is firing `onclick` of search result button which is content page

Answer (score 3):

Wrap each search textbox and button with a Panel control and set its DefaultButton property to the ID of the search button as follows:

```
<asp:Panel id="pnlSearch" DefaultButton="btnSearch" runat="server">
  <asp:TextBox id="txtSearchString" runat="server" />
  <asp:Button id="btnSearch" Text="Search" runat="server" />
</asp:Panel>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.defaultbutton.aspx

Comment: i have place master page textbox and search button in one panel and named it pnlsearch and also placed content page textbox and search in one panel and named it pnlcontentsearch. Now when i click on master page textbox it takes master page button click event. on click of master page button i am redirecting to content page search page and now i am typing different text in content page textbox and pressing enter from keyboard then also it works, but now again i am changing master page textbox value and pressing enter key now it takes content page search panel button click.

Comment: Can you please elaborate further? I didn't understand your problem.

Comment: When you debug you code and set breakpoints on the search button click event handler for both search buttons, do the events get fired correctly?

Comment: By mistake i have written my post as answer 2 please check that

Comment: @marzouka - does this approach work cross-browser in .NET 4.0? The method doesn't work cross-browser when using LinkButton's, and I've had issue in the past with Chrome not handling default button correctly.

Comment: Yes, my application is built in .Net 4.0 and i am not using link button i am using asp button control and i am facing this issue in mozilla 5.0

Comment: @Phill I haven't tested this approach with .NET 4.0 but it should work fine with 3.5. The DefaultButton approach will not work with LinkButton controls because FireFox does not provide "click()" function for anchor elements. Please review the unsupported scenarios in the MSDN link I provided above. Does your case fall under any of them?

Comment: @semmy Do you get any javascript errors when you press the enter key in your 3rd step?

Comment: @phill i have used asp button control not link button

Comment: @marzouka - Ahh ok, only the firefox one, but I wrote a work-around to, wrote my own JS to handle default click for cross-browser including firefox, for use with Link Buttons.

Comment: hey guys did you get any solution?? this issue occurs in google crome and IE8 too.

Answer (score 0):

See i have 2 search control one in master page which i am showing on every page and one in content page which is my search page which displays search result. I have written code in master page button click which will redirect to content page which displays search result. Now steps i am following is from home page i am typing some text in master page search textbox and pressing enter from keyboard. As per coding it is redirecting to my search result page which is content page. step -2 Now i am typing some text in my search result page which is content page and pressing enter from keyboard till this steps it works fine. Step - 3 Now when type some text in master page search textbox again and pressing enter from keyborad instead of taking onclick of master page search button it is firing onclick of search result button which is content page